# Logstash Not pushing logs to elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash to deliver my application logs to AWS Es.
1. Here is my logstash configuration file:

```
input {
  file {
    path  => "/home/ubuntu/*"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {

   grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<jsonf>({.*}))"}
  }
  json {
            source => "jsonf"
  }
  mutate {
        remove_field => [ "message","jsonf" ]
      }
}

output {
  amazon_es {
    hosts => ["********************************************"]
    region => "us-east-1"
    index => "lgs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

2. When i run this there was no error showing up. It says "Logstash API Started Successfully"
3. **But i am not able to see the index created in kibana.**
4. My Ec2 has a Full permission to the ES domain.
5. My Es Domain has open access

   {
             "Version": "2012-10-17",
             "Statement": [
               {
                 "Effect": "Allow",
                 "Principal": {
                   "AWS": "*"
                 },
                 "Action": "es:*",
                 "Resource": ""
               }
             ]
           }

What Am i doin wrong here

Comment: What do the Elasticsearch Logs say? I would suggest to verify that Logstash is running the pipeline properly by outputing the data (a) to the console via stdout plugin or (b) via file output plugin. If everything works fine on the Logstash side, it must be an issue within Elasticsearch or the network. If the latter two are the case, you must provide us with additional information.

Comment: HI thanks for your time, Actually i gave the wrong log file path so that's the reason nothing got pushed even thought there was no error in the config.

Comment: So the issue is solved?

Comment: yes it is solved, Thanks.